# Installation error in R, preventing use of many packages

Tags: r, rlang

I am trying to use tidyverse and multiple other programmes which I have used for along time. However now I am having an error code related to package rlang. I have tried updating this package, removing and re-installing but it still does not work. I get error messages as below. I have tried re-installing R, but does not resolve the issue. As far as I can see I am using the most up to date version of rlang. (https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rlang/).

Any advice would be brilliant, as I am going around in circles now! Thank you

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_version("rlang", version = "1.1.0", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")

Loading required package: usethis
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘usethis’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘rlang’ 1.0.6 is already loaded, but >= 1.1.0 is required
Error: package ‘usethis’ could not be loaded

library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
 .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details:
  call: NULL
  error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘rlang’ 1.0.6 is already loaded, but >= 1.1.0 is required 

install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rlang/rlang_1.1.0.tar.gz", repo=NULL, type="source")

install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rlang/rlang_1.0.6.tar.gz", repo=NULL, type="source")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but no version of Rtools compatible with the currently running version of R was found. Note that the following incompatible version(s) of Rtools were found:

  - Rtools 4.0 (installed at C:\RBuildTools\4.0)

Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/victo/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rlang/rlang_1.0.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 742508 bytes (725 KB)
downloaded 725 KB

* installing *source* package 'rlang' ...
** package 'rlang' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
ERROR: cannot remove earlier installation, is it in use?
* removing 'C:/Users/victo/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/rlang'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/victo/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/rlang'
Warning in file.copy(lp, dirname(pkgdir), recursive = TRUE, copy.date = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\victo\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\00LOCK-rlang\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll to C:\Users\victo\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll: Permission denied
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/victo/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp8AnEOG/downloaded_packages/rlang_1.0.6.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: `WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages` is telling you that you do not have the tools required to be able to build a package from source. Install it from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) depending on your R version, then restart R and RStudio (completely) and try to reinstall each package.

Comment: FYI, notice the `Archive` in `https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rlang/`, that is everything _except_ the most recent version. It lists 1.0.6 as its most recent, but https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rlang/ lists 1.1.0.

Comment: Also start a fresh session of R with none of the packages loaded that you need to update, or make sure you detach the package prior to updating. `detach("package:rlang", unload = T)` often issues occur when upgrading a loaded package.

Comment: Thank you so so much! I re-installed Rtools ( I had it but it wasnt recognising!) reinstalled R and Rstudio and by some wizardry it is working. Thank you so much for taking the time to reply and help me, saved my sanity and now I understand the errors given better for the future. thank you